# Animate Textview continually

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, animation

I want to animate a textview but it has to continue to animation all time until click the button.
Now it works just for one time, how can implement for all time until clicked button?

Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        start()
        
        binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
            //Stop
        }
    }

    private fun start() {
        val animation: Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.textviewupdown)
        binding.txt.startAnimation(animation)
    }
}
```

MainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added -> android:repeatCount="infinite" on Animation, it works.
It looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-70%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```